# Get black & white image from UIImage in iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cifilter

I want to convert image to pure black & white. I tried and got the result which is left image I have attached and the result should be the right image I have attached according to the requirements of the application.

I have used lots of **CIFilter** like (**CIColorMonochrome, CIColorControls, CIPhotoEffectTonal** etc.) but none of this is working.

Please check below code and attached result of Images.

```
- (UIImage *)imageBlackAndWhite
{
    CIImage   *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.captureImage.image, .1)];

    //CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage];

    CIImage *output = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], @"inputColor", [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]], nil].outputImage;

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgiimage = [context createCGImage:output fromRect:output.extent];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgiimage];

    CGImageRelease(cgiimage);

    return newImage;
}
```

My Result----------------------------------------------Expected Result
[image]

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972441/convert-image-to-black-and-white-ios

Comment: Single MonoChrome filter will not work, the result you want can be achieved by adding `Brightness`, or `Luminous` to the image. Try to apple couple of more filter as I said above, you will get the result. Cheers.

Comment: thanks @iphonic its's works but not expected result.

Comment: @vijay Yes, you might need to do lots of testing by combinations, its difficult. There is another way is if you have any image editor like photoshop, you try to get the exact output you want from original image, and apply same using coregraphics. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blendmode: `kCGBlendModeLuminosity` with alpha value:1.0